# Как поместить в буфер обмена (копировать) данные по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: javascript

В общем, нужна возможность помещать данные в буфер, как будто пользователь сам нажал Copy (Ctrl+V). Для IE есть простое решение:

```
document.execCommand("Copy");
```

Для FF есть документация [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Clipboard) (работоспособность не проверял). А как это сделать в Хроме и Сафари? Или может быть есть кроссбраузерное решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть Вам подойдет [первая ссылка из гугла](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/copy) по запросу "jquery copy to clipboard"?

Comment: Я не знаком с jQuery. Мне нужно написать натив-метод на JavaScript, который можно использовать из Java (GWT).

Comment: Тогда простите. :) На stackoverflow обсуждение по этому вопросу ничем не кончилось.

Comment: То есть jQuery использовать в GWT-приложении нельзя? И с помощью него (jQuery) копи-паст в браузере работает хорошо?

Comment: Почему нельзя? Можно.
Так как jq - кроссбраузерный фреймворк, то наверно копи-паст будет работать хорошо. Я не использовал этот плагин, но почему бы ему не работать?

Comment: а разве IE даст вам так что то скопировать? По-моему он спрашивает разрешения перед этим, ибо считает это небезопасным. По-сути так и есть..

Answer (score 2):

Есть вот такая штучка: http://www.logiclabz.com/javascript/copy-to-clipboard-with-javascript-on-mozilla-firefox-and-ie.aspx . Если честно, не тестил, но код похож на правду. Попробуйте, может поможет.

Comment: В общем, похоже никак нельзя это сделать. А по ссылке рассказывается, как это сделать для IE и FF. В вопросе я указал, что это я и так нашел.